# Identify a pipe coming out of the basement floor, as well as a hole in the floor?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement

I want to build a bathroom in the basement with a 36”x36” shower.

I am trying to figure out if this pipe is the vent from the main drain.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to figure out if this pipe is the vent from the main
> drain.

It is a vent, it is coming off of the top of a sanitary tee so it is a vent for a fixture (*Bathroom sink*) that would be attached to the SanTee.

The pipe coming form the bottom of the SanTee is the drain for a fixture  that would be attached to it.

The hole in the floor should be the required space for a drain/trap for a shower/tub. Presumably since the sink plumbing and a  toilet flange was roughed in there would be a capped off drain pipe under the dirt.